# vi syntax to comment out non-commented lines (cron)

Tags: unix, cron, sed, vi

Anyone know if it's possible in vi to replace only uncommented/non-blank lines with comments?

If I want to replace a commented line with something I know I can use :%s/^#/##foo##/g -- but I am looking for the opposite of this.

Example file:

```
# Some user's cron

# Test comments
00 00 * * * ~/somescript.sh
```

Expected result:

```
# Some user's cron

# Test comments
##DISABLE##00 00 * * * ~/somescript.sh
```

Answer (score 3):

```
:g/^[0-9\*]/s/^/##DISABLED##/
```

This "g/RE/" part selects all lines that begin with a number or the * character.
The "s/RE/replacement/" then does the work on all selected lines.

Comment: or `:g/^[^#]/s/^/##DISABLED##/`

Comment: Good call wfaulk. Even simpler.

Comment: You beat me to it by like 1 minute.

Answer (score 1):

```
:%s/^\([^#]\)/##DISABLE##\1/
```

Comment: What is `@`? --padding--

Comment: Sorry, that was meant to be a '%'

Answer (score 0):

```
:map q /^[^#]<Enter>0i##DISABLE##<Esc>q
1Gq
```

This works in vim, but not in stock vi, which won't do tail recursion on mappings.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i -e 's/^\([^#]\)/#\1/g' /etc/cronfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
%s/^\([^#]\)\|!\($\)/##FOO##\1/g
```

I know its a mess with all those escapes, but the first part it the line does not start with # `[^#]`, OR (The escaped pipe `\|` ) a line that is not empty ( `^$` )

Comment: You mean %s/^\\([^#]\\)\|!\\($\\)/##FOO##\1/g

Comment: Doesn't work in standard vi.  Would work without the `|` or: `:%s/^\([^#]\)/##FOO##\1/g`

Answer (score 0):

```
:%s/^\([#\n]\)\@!/##DISABLE##/g
```

the ^([#\n])\@! means "not # or newline at beginning of line"

Works for me in vim 7.2

Comment: Doesn't work in standard vi; no zero-width matches (`\@!`).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Vim, you may be interested in the [EnhCommentify.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=23) plugin which lets you easily toggle comments.